# Request from one user to one particular EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a load balancer in which there are mutiple EC2 instances.Now i want the request from one particular user should be served by one particular EC2 only not others and so on.What configuration or setting i can do to achieve this ?

Please suggest some thoughts on this scenario.

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of load balancing. What happens if that instance is not available for example? Usually, there is no valid use case to tweak a load balancer that way and there is probably a backend oriented more elegant solution. You did not explain in your question how your app identifies unique user. Is this cookie based ? Client IP address based ? Or do your app relies on some sort of tokens in the requests ?

Comment: Advisability of doing this aside ... if a given EC2 instance has a public IP, and security groups allow it, then a client can talk directly to the instance by hostname or public IP, bypassing the load balancer.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq Its Client IP address based.Also i understand the concerns you mentioned.But they want to design this way and i am clueless how can i achieve this.Please share some ideas if you can.Thanks!!!

Comment: Would sticky sessions solve your use case? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions

Comment: @maccam94 This looks good !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your client is identified by the IP address, there is no easy way to solve your problem.
Application Loadbalancer can do HTTP HEADER or HTTP PATH based routing, as shown below.  See ALB Listener Rules documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html

[image: ALB Routing]

In addition, the cookie stickiness affinity is possible.
You can have the client IP address in the HTTP Header if the client is going through a proxy and the proxy is using the X-Forwarded-For header.

As stated in a comment, for that use case, I would probably suggest to not go through the load balancer and have the client connecting to the EC2 instance directly.

Comment: .Thanks you for sharing the thoughts on this.But lets assume i dont want to identify client by IP,then in this case what should be the parameter considered to identify so that i am implement this in easy way ?

Comment: As answered, there is no easy way to handle this.  If you don't want to use client IP address, the only possibility is to identify clients based on some value in HTTP Headers, such a auth token.  The easiest would be to bypass the load balancer at all for customers that need direct conenction to your IP instances, by providing them a different DNS name for example.  There is no advantage of going through the load balancer for these customers anyway as you want them to always go to the same EC2 instance.